# How to get HttpServletRequest Attribute in Thymeleaf using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    //var rootpath=[[${httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}]];
    //var rootpath = [[${rootPath}]];;
    var rootpath=$("#rootpath").val();
    //alert(rootpath);
    var tale = new $.tale();
    function checkForm() {
        tale.post({
            url: rootpath+'/admin/login',
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result && result.success) {
                    window.location.href = rootpath+'/admin/index';
                } else {
                    tale.alertError(result.msg || '登录失败');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

I can use a hidden tag in HTML to store the value,

```
<input type="hidden" id="rootpath" th:value="${#httpServletRequest.getContextPath()}" />
```

and lately get it via

```
var rootpath=$("#rootpath").val();
```

**BUT IT IS NOT GOOD ENOUGH.**

**How can I get the request value in a direct way?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the latest Thymeleaf, this work for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript" th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/
    var tale = new $.tale();
    function checkForm() {
        tale.post({
            url: /*[[@{/admin/login}]]*/ '',
            data: $("#loginForm").serialize(),
            success: function (result) {
                if (result && result.success) {
                    window.location.href = /*[[@{/admin/index}]]*/ '';
                } else {
                    tale.alertError(result.msg || '登录失败');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

You shouldn't need to use `#httpServletRequest` to get your context path, just use Thymeleaf's standard url syntax.

Comment: **[[@{/admin/index}]]** won't work in spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-1.5.1-RELEASE. What's your thymeleaf version in use?

Comment: What does the rendered view-source look like? Did you make sure and include `th:inline="javascript"`?  I'm using Thymeleaf 3.0.2.RELEASE. (I believe spring boot 2 is when they migrated to Thymeleaf 3)

Comment: what if i need to do that from an external js file which i import using src attribute ?